# Getting duplicate values on Scrolling Listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase

Getting duplicate value on scrolling ListView, I have tried solution which are given already but still having the same problem [Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvXxH.png)

Comment: please show code

Comment: image is already attached sir!

Comment: It is best to place it as text in the question.

Comment: have a look in my code , if u can help me with this.